# php rename warning despite being successfull

Tags: php, rename

I am doing a rename so I can move a folder. The move is successful, but I keep getting a warning:

Warning: rename(site_files/259,trash/site_files/259) [function.rename]: No such file or directory in /home/oosman/public_html/lib.php on line 79

This is my code:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($file);
$d = $path_parts['dirname'];
$f = $path_parts['basename'];

$trashdir='trash/'.$d;
mkdir2($trashdir);
if(!is_dir($trashdir))
    return FALSE;

rename($file, $trashdir.'/'.$f); // this is line 79 where the warning is coming from
```

Why am I getting this warning?

FYI the mkdir2 is just my recursive mkdir function

```
function mkdir2($dir, $mode = 0755)
{
    if (@is_dir($dir) || @mkdir($dir,$mode)) return TRUE;
    if (!mkdir2(dirname($dir),$mode)) return FALSE;
    return @mkdir($dir,$mode);
}
```

Comment: You probably meant to use `rename($path_parts, $trashdir.'/'.$f);`

Comment: If you stop suppressing errors by using `@` you will probably see more warnings that will tell you the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just because the source or targeting folder does not exist.

This will remove the warning anyway but not the best way to solve the question:

```
if(file_exists($file) && file_exists($trashdir)){
    rename($file, $trashdir.'/'.$f);
}
```

In order to find out what the problem really is, please check following questions:

1.Does the source file(`site_files/259`) exist? Does it have an extension like `259.txt`?

From your log , I guess the absolute path of the original file should be `/home/oosman/public_html/site_files/259`.

2.Have you successfully created the target folder? Can you see it on the disk and get `TRUE` from `mkdir2()`?

3.I strongly suggest that you use the absolute path but not the relative path when you use `rename()`.

```
rename('/home/oosman/public_html/site_files/259', '/home/oosman/public_html/trash/site_files/259');
```

but not

```
rename('site_files/259', 'trash/site_files/259');
```

Maybe something wrong with the relative path?

Updated 2014-12-04 12:00:00 (GMT +900):

Since it is not anything mentioned above could you please log something to help me clarify?

Please change

```
rename($file, $trashdir.'/'.$f);
```

to

```
echo "Before moving:\n"
echo "Orgin:".file_exists($file)."\n";
echo "Target parent folder:".file_exists($trashdir)."\n";
echo "Target file:".file_exists($trashdir.'/'.$f)."\n";
rename($file, $trashdir.'/'.$f);
echo "After moving:\n"
echo "Orgin:".file_exists($file)."\n";
echo "Target parent folder:".file_exists($trashdir)."\n";
echo "Target file:".file_exists($trashdir.'/'.$f)."\n";
```

If this outputs:

```
Before moving:
Origin:1
Target parent folder:1
Target file:0
Warning: rename(site_files/259,trash/site_files/259) [function.rename]: No such file or directory in /home/oosman/public_html/lib.php on line 83
After moving:
Origin:0
Target parent folder:1
Target file:1
```

exactly only once, then I am out. If it doesn't, please tell me the difference.

Comment: Like I said, the move is successful. The folder does indeed get moved to the new location. So why does it give a warning?

Comment: And site_files/259 is a folder, not a file. I am moving (successfully) site_files/259 to trash/site_files/259 . But the warning appears. In another SO question similar to this, I read that the destination folder was on a different partition. In my case, I can't be sure of that 100%, but I believe its the same partition, as both folders have same root folder.

Comment: And you are sure you have only called this function once? Not something like 'moving files already moved' ?

Comment: Yes, I checked that also by adding logging. rename is only called once.

Comment: -
Before moving:
Origin:
Target parent folder:1
Target file:1
After moving:
Origin:
Target parent folder:1
Target file:1

Comment: With help of your logging, and after adding additional logging, I was able to figure it out. The code is actually getting called twice. That is why first time it moves the files, but the second time the rename operation gives a warning and probably fails. That is why the folder does move.

As to why the function was getting called twice, although I am not posting the code for that here, it was because in my jQuery, I had bound the delete handler twice to my delete button.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This one got me good. Was calling rename() twice by accident. The first one was successful the second one was giving out the error.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is simply to hide the warning:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);
rename($file, $trashdir.'/'.$f);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of issuing a 'warning' by the rename function while the transfer was well done.
The problem came from the transfer of a volume to another volume. And different rights between the source file and the destination file.
This bug is referenced in PHP: [Bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50676)

In reality, the rename() function performs the following operations :
copy, chmod, chown and unlink
And in my case I think the chown() operation fails hence the 'warning' issued.
To overcome this problem and **without simply hiding all the warnings** with `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING)`, I implemented the following code:

```
// If Source File Present and Accessible
if(@is_file($sourceFilePath))
{
    // If no error during transfer (we omit the warning with @)
    if(@rename($sourceFilePath,$destinationFilePath))
    {
        // If the transfer was really successful (and the file is accessible)
        if(@is_file($destinationFilePath))
        {
          echo "OK";
        }
        else echo "Error : File Not Really Transfered";
    }
    else echo "Error : File Not Transfered";
}
else echo "Error : Source File Not Present";
```

Hope this answer can help